# Did Daniel Bernoulli state van der Waals equation?

Tags: biographical-details

I read in some places that Daniel Bernoulli anticipated van der Waals equation by a century in section 10 of his Hydrodynamica. Most sources state that he only discovered one idea in the model; that of taking into account the size of the particles. But did he also consider the attraction between the particles? I'm unable to read his Latin work so I need someone to answer.

Comment: Please explain in more detail what "van der Waals equation" you have in mind. It would help if you mention where you came across the claim.

Comment: See I.Grattan-Guinness (ed) [Landmark writings in western mathematics](https://books.google.it/books?id=UdGBy8iLpocC&pg=PA138) (2005), **Ch.9 D.BERNOULLI, HYDRODYNAMICA (1738)** by G.K.Mikhailov, page 138: "B proposes a kinetic model of air, consisting of a number of very small (but finite) spherical particles moving in straight lines at very high velocities.Taking into account the finite size of the air particles,B obtains also a generalization of the Boyle–Mariotte law *in the spirit of the Van der Waals equation*. Unfortunately, B’s kinetic theory was disregarded over more than a century."

Comment: Thanks, but i've already read this source. Many sources claim that he took acount of the finite size of the particles, but i ask if he also thought about the \left(p + \frac{n^2 a}{V^2}\right) term of the equation. For this i need someone who is able to read the original latin of the work "Hydrodynamica".

Answer (score 1):

*References*

Section 10, §1-8, of Daniel Bernoulli, [Hydrodynamica sive de viribus et motibus fluidorum commentarii](https://books.google.it/books?id=3yRVAAAAcAAJ&printsec=frontcover), Agentorati, 1738, are discussed into:

- Clifford Truesdell, [Essays in the History of Mechanics](https://books.google.it/books?id=_crsCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA277) (1968), **Ch.VI. Early Kinetic Theories of Gases**; see page 277-on.

---

See also: Clifford Truesdell, [Rational fluid mechanics. 1687-1765](https://books.google.it/books?id=sT1cHAAACAAJ) (1954), **Part IV. The hydrodynamics of Daniel and John BERIOULLI**, page XXIII, as well as: Julian Simon Calero, [The genesis of fluid mechanics. 1640-1780](https://books.google.it/books?id=pyZIotXTX2sC&pg=PA320) (2008), page 320, where it is discussed the chapter of *Hydrodynamica* subtitled ‘Concerning Properties and Motions of Elastic Fluids, but especially of Air’.

Comment: Thank you very much for the excellent references. Right now exactly the pages i need are ommited, so i still can't read.